# Can't Move Text to top of page bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I was working on a project and as seen in the image below the my Menu & the Symbol was at the top corner across from the X icon and I later added Bootstrap API and it went down.

I was wondering if there was any way that  I can bring the Menu back up

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukydh.png

Thanks

Comment: Is there a live demo of this site somewhere? Can you post code or a jsfiddle?

Comment: can you provide the existing html and css? without it, it is very hard to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding the style: `#menuIconId {top: 0px;}` to your menu icon to remove extra space above the icon?